# Django error when migrating with default field function that queries database

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

I'm trying to create a default field callable like this:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
from django.db import models

class Preferences(models.Model):
    expiration_days = models.IntegerField(default=30)
    ... other db settings here ...

class ImportantBusinessObject(models.Model):
    expiration_date = models.DateField(default=get_default_expiration_date)

def get_default_expiration_date():
    expiration_days = Preferences.objects.first().expiration_days
    return date.today() + timedelta(days=expiration_days)
```

The idea is that there is a set of global preferences stored in the db, which affect default values on other model objects.

Everything is fine and dandy until it's time to add another field to the `Preferences` class. Then, when building the db (while running tests, for example), the migration which adds the `expiration_date` field ends up executing before the new migration adding another preference field. During the call to `get_default_expiration_date()`, the Preferences object is the latest version, but the DB hasn't gotten the newest migration, and I get a `column preferences.new_preference does not exist` error.

What's the best way to solve this?

Right now I'm disabling migrations during tests as a workaround, but I'm wondering if there's another way.

I've tried grabbing the model from the app registry from within `get_default_expiration_date()`, however it's still the latest one, not the versioned one that you're given in `migrations.RunPython` functions.

I've also tried wrapping the line that gets the `Preferences` object in a try/except block, but the db ends up in a rollback state, and I can't continue.

Other bits:

- I'm using Django 1.8
- In my actual app, the `Preferences` class is actually a db singleton using django-solo.

**UPDATE**: Clarifying the order of operations

Here is sort of a timeline of what's happening:

1. `preferences/migrations/initial_0001.py`: initial preferences, includes `expiration_days`
2. `business/migrations/initial_0001.py`: initial business object, depends on `preferences 0001`
3. `preferences/migrations/add_pref_0002.py`: add a new field to `Preferences`

As soon as I define the migration in step #3, things start to break because when running to add the migration from step #2, `get_default_expiration_date` is called which throws the error. From the comment thread below about updating dependencies, my point was that in order to do that, every time I add a new preferences migration, I need to update the dependencies of the previously defined `business/migrations/initial_0001.py` (and any others that behave similarly). Hopefully this clarifies the situation a bit.

Comment: Have you tried editing the [dependencies](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/#dependencies) so that the `Preferences` migration runs first?

Comment: I hadn't tried that. It feels weird to edit the dependencies of a previously created migration to depend on a new one (and then having to manually manage dependencies every time I add a new migration to `Preferences`.) That may be another workaround, though.

Comment: I'm confused about what code is running in between the two migrations. When running tests it should reconstruct the database by running all migrations before any test code is executed. Do you have a data migration that is setting the new preference on existing objects?

Comment: Updated question to try to clarify

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're running into the issue discussed in the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/#historical-models):

> Because it’s impossible to serialize arbitrary Python code, these historical models will not have any custom methods that you have defined.

This normally comes up in the context of a data migration that is creating model instances. If you weren't creating any instances during the migrations then `get_default_expiration_date()` would never be executed, and you wouldn't have a problem. (I'm not sure what's doing it in your case, maybe something to do with django-solo or another package you're using?)

I think the easiest solution in this case is to make sure that your default functions only reference the fields that they need, that way they aren't generating references to SQL columns that might not exist yet. When you get the whole object like you're doing now it tries to get all the fields, and it looks at the current (not historical) model definition to see what those fields are.

If you use `values()` (or `only()`) the generated SQL will only reference the fields you specify:

```
def get_default_expiration_date():
    expiration_days = Preferences.objects.values("expiration_days")[0]["expiration_days"]
```

Comment: Yes! So the actual answer was a little more involved due to django-solo, but this got me 90% of the way there, thanks. For completeness, django-solo creates the record in the db if it's not there yet, so I had to handle that case by using the field default value if the record was missing.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for us. We faced a similar scenario and got stuck for quite a while. If anyone is using get instead of filter, try this my_obj = MyModel.objects.values('id').get(name='USA')